# 10 digit decimal to binary conversion not works

Tags: php, binary

I am facing issue while I convert 10 digit decimal to binary. When I convert up to 9 digits it perfectly works at the same time when I use decbin() function for 10 digit long it doesn't work.

For an example when I convert decimal to binary using decbin() this function with any inputs up to 9 digits then I will get proper out. When I use 10 digit decimal I getting same output (`1111111111111111111111111111111`) for  numbers between `2200000000 - 9999999999` as input.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>test</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$num = $_GET[n];
$bin = decbin($num);    // Decimal to binary
?>
<table>
<tr><td>Number:</td><td><?php echo $num; ?></td></tr>
<tr><td>Binary:</td><td><a href='binary.php?b=<?php echo $bin; ?>'><?php echo $bin; ?></a></td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I visit `number.php?n=2200000845` it shows `1111111111111111111111111111111` as result.

Anyone please solve this problem..

Comment: It does work for me!! I get `1001001100101100000001011011101010` and by the way it is `$bin2 = decbin($num2);` right?

Comment: kindly check it with my updated code

Comment: It does work again: `Number: 9999999999
Binary: 1001010100000010111110001111111111`

Comment: @Thamizhan: did u test with my code? now im checked. i get same 1111111111111111111111111111111 output for 9999999999

Comment: @DineshKumar Do you try it on 64-bit machine?

Comment: @MrRP: thanks for the info.. now it works in an another system..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 32-bit system the maximum decimal number is: 4294967295

Check it: http://php.net/manual/en/function.decbin.php

Comment: MrRP, thanks now it has been fixed.. i have shared linux hosting.. how can i view weather 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: The phpinfo can tells you. E.g.: `System Linux frontend 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.68-1+deb7u6 x86_64`

Comment: @Dinesh Kumar use "uname –a" http://www.howtogeek.com/198615/how-to-check-if-your-linux-system-is-32-bit-or-64-bit/

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$num` for `$bin2` also. Change

```
$bin2 = decbin($num);
```

to

```
$bin2 = decbin($num2);
```